# Presenting Multiple Encodings in XML

Tags: python, xml, json, encoding, utf-8

I'm making available an email API that allows you to obtain the content of certain emails via XML/JSON.

My problem is, I have a list view where I want to present the text of multiple emails at once. And the text is encoded using different encodings for each.

I tried placing the specific encoded text instead CDATA sections of the XML so it would be allowed. But now I still obtain the error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 45 at column 23: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x10 0x30 0x30 0x33
```

I have all sorts of character encodings in these emails ranging from ISO to Latin, etc. Is there a "universal" encoding I can declare in the XML encoding as not to have errors?

JSON serialization is working beautifully.

Comment: Encode them with base64 or something and use utf-8 for the xml file.

Comment: Have you got a way of knowing the encoding of the incoming data? In that case, decode it to unicode and encode it in UTF-8 before creating the XML.

Comment: @ubik That is a great suggestion. I would actually ask you to place that as a reply so I can try it and mark it as the accepted answer if it works out.

Comment: @gatto That is interesting but I would like it, if possible, to be "readable" when viewing the XML. Encoding it in base64 would somewhat defeat that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way of knowing the encoding of the incoming data, just decode it to Unicode and then encode it in UTF-8 before creating the XML.

```
# e.g. latin1 -> utf-8
text.decode('latin1').encode('utf-8')
```